# Who provided the C header file?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I use Ubuntu(Linux)+ gcc as a example.

- `stdio.h`
- `sys/socket.h`
- `poll.h`
- `pthread.h`

which on Ubuntu Linux(with gcc installed), are respectively provided by which organization? GNU? Linux ? ISO? Ubuntu?

And what about the corresponding library?

Comment: Each header usually have a copyright notice inside. Use gcc -H to understand which header files are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are library headers that are part of C library installed on your system.

On Ubuntu **glibc** implementation is used (GNU C library).
Some other examples of C libraries:
uclibc (embedded), avr-libc (embedded), dietlibc, klibc, elibc_FreeBSD ...

ISO/IEC has created standard and these libraries follow it.

```
~ head -n 20 /usr/include/stdio.h
/* Define ISO C stdio on top of C++ iostreams.
   Copyright (C) 1991, 1994-2010, 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library.

   The GNU C Library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
   modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
   version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

   The GNU C Library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
   Lesser General Public License for more details.

   You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
   License along with the GNU C Library; if not, write to the Free
   Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
   02111-1307 USA.  */
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is maintained by Canonical, so they are the ones who assemble the packages.

And the standard C library headers, as part of the GNU implementation of the C standard library, are maintained by GNU.org, so that is the source Canonical takes it from.

Comment: Actually headers (nor implementations) are not part of gcc bundle (though canonical/ubuntu may call it gcc-devel or something).
Most linux distros use gnu C library (glibc) that includes these.

Answer (score 1):

They are provided by GNU.

First lines of `/usr/include/stdio.h`:

```
/* Define ISO C stdio on top of C++ iostreams.
   Copyright (C) 1991, 1994-2008, 2009, 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This file is part of the GNU C Library...
```

Answer (score 0):

gcc is a GNU compiler whatever system it's installed on